# How to clear all context in Watson Assistant like click 'clear' on 'try in out'

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to clear all context variable when user input 'cancel'. Should I have to use API of Watson Assistant?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate - the "duplicate" question discusses how to remove 1 context variable and not all and does not answer what the user is asking here. The answer is actually in the documentation: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-clearing-context - one needs to call `.clear()` method on `context`, e.g. `<? context.clear() ?>`